# Using airolib-ng with crunch and then using the file using aircrack-ng gives unexpected result

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, wpa2, aircrack-ng

I'm using **airlib-ng** and **crunch** to generate password Database and use that Password Database in **aircrack-ng** to crack the Captured Handshake of a WPA2 Wireless Network.

Here are my terminal Commands and Output -

```
root@VAIO-PC:~/Desktop/files# crunch 8 8 1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz --stdout | airolib-ng testdb -import passwd -
Crunch will now generate the following amount of data: 25389989167104 bytes
24213780 MB
23646 GB
23 TB
0 PB
Crunch will now generate the following number of lines: 2821109907456 
Database <testdb> does not already exist, creating it...
Database <testdb> successfully created
Reading file...
^CCrunch ending at 1111y3z4id lines ignored.
root@VAIO-PC:~/Desktop/files# clear
```

Now, I've generated a testdb which I'll be using with `-r` switch to crack the handshake file (*.cap).

```
root@VAIO-PC:~/Desktop/files# aircrack-ng '/root/Desktop/hs/TEST-NET.cap' -r '/root/Desktop/files/testdb' 
Opening /root/Desktop/hs/TEST-NET.cap
Read 4 packets.

   #  BSSID              ESSID                     Encryption

   1  AA:8E:E8:04:02:EE  TEST-NET                  WPA (1 handshake)

Choosing first network as target.

Opening /root/Desktop/hs/TEST-NET (copy).cap
Reading packets, please wait...


                                 Aircrack-ng 1.2 rc4

Quitting aircrack-ng...
root@VAIO-PC:~/Desktop/files#
```

But it quits for an unexpected reason, can anyone here tell me the problem here? Also a .journal file gets deleted. I dunno what's the problem, I tried searching in forums and other website but I didn't find much help regarding this.

Related - https://tools.kali.org/wireless-attacks/airolib-ng
but it uses a wordlist instead of generating them using crunch.

I think that the password database file is about 50mb and the text password is more that 500 mb, so is my PC running so fast that it completes the whole process in wink of an eye?

Comment: You quit the `crunch` process early. How many lines in the file? Could it simply be that it reached the end of the passwords and exited normally?

Comment: @schroeder the database library was already created, it was just checking if there are some faulty strings or not, airolib works in this way

Comment: @schroeder Also, the database file is 50mb

Comment: @schroeder I think that it quits so quickly that I don think that it even tries any password to crack before in order to quit also, it should show that it has completed the cracking by showing the last password in order to know that it's completed

Comment: you think that 1gb of password can be completed in a fraction of second? it's an old i3 CPU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of using airlib-ng is to speed up things, computing in advance all the possible PMK (pair-wise master key) combination used during the handshake, which are derived from the password **and** the ESSID.

So you'll need to perform some additional steps:

1) Import a list of ESSIDs:

```
$ airolib-ng testdb --import essid your_essids.txt
```

2) Compute the PMKs using all possible password+ESSID combinations:

```
$ airolib-ng testdb --batch
```

Your code should work afterwards.

Comment: The aircrack-ng confirmed a bug about that,